# Java JNA Send an Array of Doubles to C

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, jna

I want to use Java JNA to send an array of doubles to C, C will process data and write something into the array of doubles. Then I could use java to read it out. Btw C code is in a shared lib.

But My code does not work.

C function I am calling:

```c
int swe_calc_ut(double *xx);
```

Java code to call that function:

(already establish the connection with C shared lib, the .so file
That part has been tested and work fine. So ignore that part.)

```java
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.*;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

// declare the C function
int swe_calc_ut(DoubleByReference xx);

// call the C function
DoubleByReference xx = new DoubleByReference();
swe_calc_ut(xx);
```

Error:

```
malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I guess it's related to pointer operation cause arrays are all pointer in C. But don't really know what to code.

Answer (score 0):

`DoubleByReference` only allocates space for a single (8-byte) `double` value, but you've specified an array.

JNA can handle primitive arrays just fine without any special treatment.  See this example at JNA's [PointersAndArrays](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/PointersAndArrays.md) doc:

```c
// Original C declarations
void fill_buffer(int *buf, int len);
void fill_buffer(int buf[], int len); // same thing with array syntax
```

```java
// Equivalent JNA mapping
void fill_buffer(int[] buf, int len);
```

So in your case, you could simply call

```java
// declare the C function
int swe_calc_ut(double[] xx);

// call the C function
double[] xx = new double[size];
swe_calc_ut(xx);
```

Note that all you're really passing under the hood is a pointer to the start of the array, and there is no size information given.   Either the API for the function specifies the size of the array, or there must be a way for you to communicate that size; otherwise the C side won't know where the array ends.

You could also pass the pointer by allocating a buffer using `new Memory(Native.LONG_DOUBLE_SIZE * arraySize)` and setting/getting the double array with the associated `Pointer` getters.